# Cannot Access user profile using JWT in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-7

I have used JWT in Laravel for user Authentication

Auth Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Verified;
use Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
   
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login', 'register']]);
    }

     /**
     * Get a JWT via given credentials.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function login(Request $request){
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json($validator->errors(), 422);
        }

        if (! $token = auth()->attempt($validator->validated())) {
            return response()->json(['status'=>true,'error_message' => 'Invalid Credentials'], 401);
        }

        return $this->createNewToken($token);
    }

      /**
     * Register a User.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function register(Request $request) {
        $messages = [
            'password.confirmed' => 'Password Confirmation should match the Password',
            'password.min' => ' Password should be minimum 6 digits',
        ];
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required|string|between:2,100',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:100|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|confirmed|min:6',
        ],$messages);

        if($validator->fails()){
            return response()->json($validator->errors(), 422);
        }

        $user = User::create(array_merge(
                    $validator->validated(),
                    ['password' => bcrypt($request->password)]
                ));

        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Successfully registered',
        ], 201);
    }

      /**
     * Log the user out (Invalidate the token).
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function logout() {
        auth()->logout();

        return response()->json(['message' => 'User successfully signed out']);
    }

      /**
     * Refresh a token.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function refresh() {
        return $this->createNewToken(auth()->refresh());
    }

    /**
     * Get the authenticated User.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function userProfile() {
        return response()->json(auth()->user());
    }

     /**
     * Get the token array structure.
     *
     * @param  string $token
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    protected function createNewToken($token){
        return response()->json([
            'access_token' => $token,
            'token_type' => 'bearer',
            'expires_in' => auth()->factory()->getTTL() * 60,
            'user' => auth()->user()
        ]);
    }



}
```

> routes :

```
Route::group([
    'middleware' => ['api'],
    'prefix' => 'auth'

], function ($router) {
    Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
    Route::post('/register', [AuthController::class, 'register']);
    Route::post('/logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout']);
    Route::post('/refresh', [AuthController::class, 'refresh']);
    Route::get('/user-profile', [AuthController::class, 'userProfile']);
```

Login and register is working

but when i access user-profile route getting this error :

> Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route
> [login] not defined. in file
> C:\wamp64\www\project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator.php
> on line 420

and i cannot get id of user if some user is logged in using : `auth()->user()->id`

> auth.php

```
   'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
```

> Model :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
#use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;

class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{   #HasFactory, 
     use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'otp',
        'user_verification_token',
        'verified',
        'token',
        'email_verified_at'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function getJWTIdentifier() {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    public function getJWTCustomClaims() {
        return [];
    }    

}
```

Any suggestion is highly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Error message says there is no route that named as 'login'

```
Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login'])->name('login');
```

Comment: Erkan Ozkok : Thanks i added login route but now i'm getting this error The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST. when i change route to POST then POST is also not working

Comment: You should use POST method when you try to log in.  e.g. you can use postman. 
Did you implement jwt for an API application?

Comment: Ozkok: Login route is already post request and i have implemented jwt for api application, initially route for profile was get that also i changed to post, i was unable to access profile route function that is within Auth controller else login and register are working in postman also